# Запуск onboard вместе с приложением

Tags: c++, qt

Можно ли вставить `system("onboard");` в приложение Qt при его запуски от `root`?

Так чтобы GUI не зависал и оба работали паралельно.

Comment: а что такое onboard?

Comment: @KoVadim экранная клавиатура в ubuntu

Comment: Вам нужен http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html - оно умеет запускать "асинхронно"

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, с одной стороны помогло, правда есть проблемка. Первая программа стартует в Fullscreen и из за этого, экранную клавиатуру не видно. Возможно ли это как-то решить?

Comment: я не знаю, умеет ли экранная клавиатура стать поверх Вашего приложения. Может и нет. В любом случае - надо экспериментировать и пробовать.